# Keras: Two simultaneous layers, where one of them does a convolution of preceding layer's output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to achieve such model's connectivity:

Input image 1 -> Convolutional layer 1

Input image 2 -> Layer, where each pixel of the input is connected to just  **one**  weight, i.e. 1:1 correspondence -> Convolutional layer 2

After that, these two layers will follow standard CNN's structure, but I have difficulty implementing two simultaneous layers where one of them is simply taking the input and learning how much to treat each individual pixel, without looking at the neighbors.

The second input image should follow something similar:

[image]

I know this isn't standard, but is there any way to achieve this in Keras(or Tensorflow)?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you're looking for:

https://keras.io/layers/local/

Basically:

> The LocallyConnected1D layer works similarly to the Conv1D layer, except that weights are unshared, that is, a different set of filters is applied at each different patch of the input.

In this case, you would like to use this layer with kernel size (1,1) to assign only one weight value to one pixel of the image.

Comment: Elaborating on your answer, to get the "just one weight" part I think the OP needs to use kernel size `(1,1)` and 1 filter

Comment: @GPhilo: Sure I forgot to mention that :) I have edited my answer based on your answer.